# How to access a specific student's information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

If the `students.txt` file was like this:

```
michael jackson:
Civil id: 102931023
Gender: male
```

In the `show_student()` function I knew only how to check if the student is in the file or not, but I couldn't access the student information.

How can I access to it?

**Code**

```py
import csv
import sys
import pathlib

file_path = pathlib.Path("students.txt")
if file_path.exists():
    pass
else:
    file = open("students.txt", "a+")
def login():
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    if username == "a" and password == "b":
        menu()
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
        login()
def menu():
    print("*" * 20 + " Main Menu " + "*" * 20)
    print(" " * 20 + "A: Register student" + " " * 20)
    print(" " * 20 + "B: Show students" + " " * 20)
    print(" " * 20 + "C: Show specific student" + " " * 20)
    print(" " * 20 + "D: Quit" + " " * 20)
    print("*" * 20 + " Main Menu " + "*" * 20)
    operation = input("Enter operation: ")
    if operation.strip().lower() == "a":
        register_student()
    elif operation.strip().lower() == "b":
        show_students()
    elif operation.strip().lower() == "c":
        show_student()
    elif operation.strip().lower() == "d":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid operation.")
        menu()
def register_student():
    student_civil_id = input("Student id: ")
    student_first = input("Student first name: ")
    student_last = input("Student last name: ")
    student_gender = input("Student gender: ")
    student_full = student_first + " " + student_last
    with open("students.txt", "a+") as studentInfo:
        info = [student_full + ": " + "\n    Civil id: " + student_civil_id + "\n    Gender: " + student_gender]
        studentInfo.write("\n" + student_full + ": " + "\n    Civil id: "
                          + student_civil_id + "\n    Gender: " + student_gender)
        print("Student has been registered.")
def show_students():
    with open("students.txt") as studentInfo:
        print(studentInfo.read())


def show_student():
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    with open("students.txt") as studentInfo:
        if student_name.strip().lower() in studentInfo.read():
            print("Student exists.")
        else:
            print("Student not exists.")
login()
```

Comment: Access it in what sense? How do you want `show_student()` to work or do what?

Comment: I want the show_student() function to check the student name (which is taken from the input) if it is in the file it will the show the student data(the gender and the civil id) if the student name is not in the file it will prints the student doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you have many students in `students.txt` file as:

```
michael jackson:
Civil id: 102931023
Gender: male
james smith:
Civil id: 165468798
Gender: male
```

With this file, you can find the index of the specific student, split the text starting from that index, and take the first 3 items from the returned list. At the end, you can use `join()` function while printing.

```
def show_student():
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    with open("students.txt") as f:
        text = f.read()

    student_position = text.find(student_name.strip().lower())

    if student_position != -1:
        info = "\n".join(text[student_position:].split("\n")[:3])
        print("Student information:")
        print(info)
    else:
        print("Student does not exists.")
```

Comment: You're welcome. You may give this answer +1 and click acceptance sign if this is the answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to match the block of information

```
import re
form = r'{}:\nCivil id: \d+\nGender: [a-z]+'

def show_student():
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    with open("students.txt") as studentInfo:
        name = student_name.strip().lower()
        pat = re.compile(form.format(name), re.MULTILINE)
        try:
            print(pat.findall(studentInfo.read())[0])
        except:
            print("Student does not exist.")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change your def to something like:

```
 def show_student():
    student_name = input("Student name: ")
    with open("students.txt") as studentInfo:
        studentData = studentInfo.readLines()
        if len(studentData) > 0 and student_name.strip().lower() in studentData[0]:
            print(*studentData[1:])
        else:
            print("Student not exists.")
```

To make your life easier, you might want to look into creating structured data using json, xml, csv or something similar. How do you know that michael jackson: is a name?

Comment: OP asks for `show_student()` function, not `show_students()`.